# golint execution returns nothing

Tags: go, golint

I'm coding exercise for exercism.io. And my mentor said that my code should be checked by some go linters, and he suggested me to try golint and golangci-lint. 
I installed golint via `go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint`, and started it:

```
rustam:hamming $ golint hamming.go 
rustam:hamming $
```

but it returns nothing.
Also if I use golangci-lint there is same result — just nothing. And I have no idea why.

There is my code, full of style mistakes:

```
// Package hamming is Exercism.io exercise
package hamming

import "errors"

// Distance — Calculating Hamming Distance for two DNA strands
func Distance(a, b string) (int, error) {

    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return 0, errors.New("Strands should be equal size")
    }

    if len(a) == 0 || len(b) == 0 {
        return 0, nil
    }

    var hd int = 0

    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        if a[i] != b[i] {
            hd++
        }
    }

    return hd, nil
}
```

And there is my go env:

```
rustam:hamming $ go env
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/rustam/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/Users/rustam/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/rustam/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/rustam/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.4/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.13.4/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/4j/4rjv22zs1pb68wssv5gn2wfw0000gn/T/go-build148685464=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

and my ~/.bash_profile

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$HOME/go/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

I'd appreciate it if you could point out my mistakes.

Comment: When the linter returns nothing, that usually means it found no problems. Do you have reason to think it should find a problem?

Comment: Yep. My mentor send his linter execution and there was some messages like 
`$ golint hamming.go
hamming.go:17:15: should drop = 0 from declaration of var hd; it is the zero value
`

Comment: Well I can confirm locally that neither `golint` nor `golaingci-lint` find any problem with that file, using default configuration.

Comment: @Volker: That's a matter of opinion, and "best practice" (if one exists) is usually context-specific, which you can't expect a linter to always get right.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But I'm some confused now. I have thought maybe linting non-main functions can't be done, but I don't know...

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: I just don't know what to do next. Yes I can fix now that `int` problem, but I can't know what mentor's linter find next time.

Comment: Ask your mentor. That's what mentors are for. Apparently he gave you a slightly incorrect assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go, the minimal checks might be the Go tools, `go fmt`, `go vet`, and `golint`.

Here is a minimum, reproducible example (see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) that shows that your `hamming.go` program passes all current checks.

[Command golint](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/lint/golint)

```
$ go version
go version devel +075c20cea8 Thu Dec 26 13:53:31 2019 +0000 linux/amd64
$ go fmt hamming.go
$ go vet hamming.go
$ go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint
go: downloading golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20191125180803-fdd1cda4f05f
go: found golang.org/x/lint/golint in golang.org/x/lint v0.0.0-20191125180803-fdd1cda4f05f
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20191125144606-a911d9008d1f
go: golang.org/x/tools upgrade => v0.0.0-20191226230302-065ed046f11a
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20191226230302-065ed046f11a
$ golint hamming.go
$ cat hamming.go
// Package hamming is Exercism.io exercise
package hamming

import "errors"

// Distance — Calculating Hamming Distance for two DNA strands
func Distance(a, b string) (int, error) {

    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return 0, errors.New("Strands should be equal size")
    }

    if len(a) == 0 || len(b) == 0 {
        return 0, nil
    }

    var hd int = 0

    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        if a[i] != b[i] {
            hd++
        }
    }

    return hd, nil
}
$
```

---

> Comment: My mentor send his linter execution and there was some messages like
>
> ```
> $ golint hamming.go hamming.go:17:15: 
> should drop = 0 from declaration of var hd; it is the zero value
> ```
>
> – Rustery

Your mentor is using an old, obsolete version of `golint`. For the current version, they should run

```
go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint
```

---

Has your mentor explained the limited purpose of `golint`? For example, "Golint is not perfect, and has both false positives and false negatives. Do not treat its output as a gold standard."

> [Golint is a linter for Go source code.](https://github.com/golang/lint/blob/master/README.md)
>
> **Purpose**
>
> Golint differs from gofmt. Gofmt reformats Go source code, whereas
>   golint prints out style mistakes.
>
> Golint differs from govet. Govet is concerned with correctness,
>   whereas golint is concerned with coding style. Golint is in use at
>   Google, and it seeks to match the accepted style of the open source Go
>   project.
>
> The suggestions made by golint are exactly that: suggestions. Golint
>   is not perfect, and has both false positives and false negatives. Do
>   not treat its output as a gold standard. We will not be adding pragmas
>   or other knobs to suppress specific warnings, so do not expect or
>   require code to be completely "lint-free". In short, this tool is not,
>   and will never be, trustworthy enough for its suggestions to be
>   enforced automatically, for example as part of a build process. Golint
>   makes suggestions for many of the mechanically checkable items listed
>   in Effective Go and the CodeReviewComments wiki page.

---

Here is my attempt at a solution:

```
package hamming

import "errors"

// Distance returns the Hamming distance for two DNA strings of equal length.
// DNA strings are constructed from the alphabet {A, C, G, T}.
func Distance(a, b string) (int, error) {
    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return 0, errors.New("strings should be of equal length")
    }

    d := 0
    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        if a[i] != b[i] {
            d++
        }
    }
    return d, nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @peter! I am agree with you. I have already passed my exercise and told my mentor that golint is not a gold standard and that my tools can be different  than his.

Answer (score 2):

You should define the confidence level (**min_confidence** argument).

E.g: `golint -min_confidence 0 your_file_to_test`

See the golint usage:

```
golint -h
Usage of golint:
    golint [flags] # runs on package in current directory
    golint [flags] [packages]
    golint [flags] [directories] # where a '/...' suffix includes all sub-directories
    golint [flags] [files] # all must belong to a single package
Flags:
  -min_confidence float
        minimum confidence of a problem to print it (default 0.8)
  -set_exit_status
        set exit status to 1 if any issues are found
```